# How to count all words that has sequence number? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt file that contains lists of websites. All website are listed as:

```
web1=www.facebook.com
web1pass=password123
web2=www.instagram.com
web2pass=password123
web3=www.youtube.com
web3pass=password123
web4=www.twitter.com
web4pass=password123
```

I want to count all "web" words that have a sequence numbers. The code I have is:

```
with open(datafile, "r") as file:
   data = file.readlines()
   web_count = 0
            
   for line in data:
      if line.split("=")[0] == "web": # I thought using web* might work.
         web_count = web_count + 1
            
    print(f"{web_count} websites found.")
```

Is there a way to write a code that counts all websites? Best if without any modules. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` to get the substrings like `web1`, `web2`, then create the `set` to remove any duplicates finally pass it to the builtin `len` to get the count

```py
import re

>>> len(set(re.findall('web\d+', line)[0] for line in f.readlines())) #f is fileBuffer
#output:
4
```

If you don't want to use regex, You may be able to do it with string methods but that will be unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Thank you. I guess using regex is the best option here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
with open(datafile, "r") as file:
   data = file.readlines()
   web_count = 0
            
   for line in data[::2]:
      if line.startswith("web"):
         web_count += 1
            
   print(f"{web_count} websites found.")
```

Only goes through lines 0, 2, 4 ... (data[::2]).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are tying to check if "web" is present at the beginning of the text. You might wanna go for [`startwith`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith).

Example :

```
text = "web132=blabla.com"

result = text.startswith('web')
print(result) #True
```

I'm not sure about the sequence number. If you want to be sure that the text has a sequence of numbers right after the "web" string, then you should definitely use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). A simple regex should do the trick, something among : `(?:web)\d+`

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
with open(datafile, "r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    web_count = 0
    for line in data:
        target  = line.split("=")[0]
        is_web = target[:3]=="web"           # check if the first 3 is web
        is_sequence = target[3:].isnumeric() # check if the following is a number
        if is_web and is_sequence: 
            web_count = web_count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex, `re`, module. It is include in the standard python library.

You could use the `search` function to look for `'web'` in the string.

**Code:**

```
import re

with open(datafile, "r") as file:
   data = file.readlines()
   web_count = 0
            
   for line in data:
      if re.search('web', line):
         web_count = web_count + 1
            
    print(f"{web_count} websites found.")
```

**Output:**

```
8 websites found.
```

If you didn't want to match the passwords.

**Code:**

```
import re

with open(datafile, "r") as file:
   data = file.readlines()
   web_count = 0
            
   for line in data:
      if re.search('web\d+=', line):
         web_count = web_count + 1
            
    print(f"{web_count} websites found.")
```

**Output:**

```
4 websites found.
```